# How To Access Repository Secret

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, operating-system, environment-variables

I've made a repository on GitHub and have added a Repository secret. However, I can't seem to grab the secret's value. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a workaround for this. Instead of using GitHub to store my secrets, I used a `.env` file and `.gitignore` to hide this file.

Giving a TOKEN value in the `.env` file, I call it within Python by importing `os` and `dotenv` like so:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

import os
token = os.getenv("TOKEN")
```